# Is PCB layouting and manufacturing process added in dissertation?

Tags: writing-style, electrical-engineering, all-but-dissertation

Should I add PCB layouting and manufacturing process pictures in dissertation?

Comment: Please provide more info. What is the focus of your dissertation? What role does layouting and manufacturing play  in your research?

Comment: The results and objectives are based on the testing (not the usual hardware setup testing)carried out on the component assembly for which PCB has been designed. I have added the schematic design, but I was not sure about adding the layouting too.

Comment: Does the board construction present any unusual problems to overcome for the testing to work (for example test signals having ribbon cable connectors are not even a little bit special, but flying leads for oddly-shaped components might be, especially if "poor probe connection" is a possible outcome of the testing).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless it is the focus of the thesis ie a new process compared to previous or existing processes, then it belongs in an appendix if at all.

As the question in the body is different, then if the section / paragraph has a relevant discussion of something to do with the board, a picture might be useful.